# How to use a global constant instead of a class constant in PHP version 5.6

Tags: php, constants, monolog, class-constants

I'm using [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) to create my app's logging system. In the core app file, after I create a new Monolog object, I need to select the log level that I want to print in the log file. I want to use a global constant `LOG_LEVEL` which could be 'DEBUG', 'INFO', etc. I need the Monolog class to treat its value as a class constant.

```
// content of config.php
// Here I declare the constants in a separate file called 'config.php'
define("LOG_FILE", "patch/to/my/log.log");
define("LOG_LEVEL", "ERROR");

// content of app.php
require 'config.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$container['logger'] = function($c) {
    $logger = new \Monolog\Logger('logger');
    error_log('log level ' . LOG_LEVEL); // prints 'log level ERROR'

    $fileHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(LOG_FILE, $logger::LOG_LEVEL); // here I get the error 'Undefined class constant LOG_LEVEL'
    //the normal syntax would be '$logger::ERROR' in this case and that works fine

    $logger->pushHandler($fileHandler);
    return $logger;
};
```

I need the 'LOG_LEVEL' constant to be used as 'ERROR' by the monolog class, not as 'LOG_LEVEL'. What am I doing wrong here, been searching an answer for hours now without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are now doing `$logger::LOG_LEVEL`, which is taking the 'LOG_LEVEL' out of the class whichever `$logger` is (in this case a `\Monolog\Logger`). That doesn't have a static variable named LOG_LEVEL, thus you get the undefined.
You have just have 'LOG_LEVEL' defined, out of any class, so:

```
 $fileHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(LOG_FILE, LOG_LEVEL);
```

---

Fancy solution:

You could do a static class and include that in your main page:

```
Class CONFIG {
    public static $LOG_LEVEL = 'default Value';
}

// Then you can use this anywhere:
CONFIG::$LOG_LEVEL
$fileHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(LOG_FILE, CONFIG::$LOG_LEVEL);
```

The advantage of this is having only one file for configs, not scattered across all kinds of files, which'll become very annoying very fast.

Comment: But they don't want to pass the string value "ERROR". If `LOG_FILE` is set to "ERROR" they want to pass `$logger::ERROR`. Basically they want variable variables, but with constants. (I think.)

Comment: Now that I see it I feel so stupid. Don't know where my head was, didn't code for some time but it seams I have a huge blank in my head. I need to be more careful in the future. Your solution is perfect, even the solutions from the colleagues bellow are good. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Logger::getLevels()` like the following:

```
$log_level = $logger->getLevels()[LOG_LEVEL];
$fileHandler = new ...StreamHandler(LOG_FILE, $log_level);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a static class and include that...

```
class GLOBALCONF{
    public static $VALUE= 'Something in here';
}

// Use it where you want
GLOBALCONF::$VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Monolog [has a function](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Logger.php#L408) to convert an error level as as string to its own internal value. Just change your code to this:

```
$fileHandler = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler(LOG_FILE, $logger::toMonologLevel(LOG_LEVEL));
```